# need a front page (cover) before title page (apa6.cls)

Tags: titles, apa6, front-matter

I am new to LateX and want to create my M.Sc. Article with it (psychology, so I am using the `apa6.cls`). But here's a problem, I didn't find a solution for as of yet:

I need a front/cover page as first page which appears before the usual title page (I am working in man style). Problem is, I would have to insert it right after begin document. But if the `\maketitle` command creating the title page doesn't come right after the begin document, it doesn't work correctly, as is also noted in the manual of the `apa6.cls`. That is, the Running Head is displayed without saying "RUNNING HEAD: HERE IS MY RUNNINGHEAD" but only "HERE IS MY RUNNING HEAD", so only the Running head itself, on my title page (hope you know what I mean).

Inserting a front page from another file with `\input` doesn't work either.

```
\documentclass[ngerman,man,12pt,a4paper,noextraspace,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
\input{Deckblatt}
\maketitle
```

("Deckblatt" is german for front page)

Thanks for your Posts!

Comment: One idea: create the cover page in a separate document, and then include the pdf using `pdfpages` package. Perhaps not very elegant, but it might work

Comment: I already had the idea to create the cover page separately from the document and put it together in the end, but i think that's not what I am using LateX for. :-) Don't know how that pdf package you mentioned works, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `apa6` class defines two page styles: `titlepage` and `otherpage`. The phrase "RUNNING HEAD" will appear only on pages with the `titlepage` style.  Assuming you want this phrase to appear only on the `apa6` title page and not on your extra title page, we can do this by using `\thispagestyle{titlepage}` before the `\maketitle` command:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,man,12pt,a4paper,noextraspace,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\title{A long title}
\author{An author}
\abstract{\kant[1]}
\shorttitle{A short title}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{.3\textheight}
\begin{center}
This is my extra title page
\end{center}
\pagestyle{otherpage}
\clearpage\setcounter{page}{1}
\thispagestyle{titlepage}\maketitle
\kant
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that doesn't solve my problem. The issue was, that when \maketitle doesn't come immediately after \begin{document}, as it is also the case in your code, there is no "RUNNING HEAD:" before my running head ("A title" in your example) on the title page. It hast to be "RUNNING HEAD: A title" on the title page and "A title" as the running head/shorttile on all following pages. Your page numbering is fine for me - cover page without and title page as 1.

Comment: Do you want the "RUNNING HEAD" line on your *extra* page, or on the title page created by `\maketitle`?

Comment: the cover page includes just my name, title etc. without a running head or page nr.

Comment: The next page (title page) 
is pretty similar, but additionally including a running head which is labeled as running head by having "RUNNING HEAD:" 
put in front, but only on the title page and not on all following pages, where only the running head itself appears. 
That "RUNNING HEAD:" in front of the running head on the title page, created by `\maketitle` , is missing in your code above.

Comment: I think that is due to `\maketitle` not instantly appearing after `begin{document}` as it should regarding to the pdf manual of the `apa6.cls`. So short answer: on title page, with "RUNNING HEAD:" put in front. ;-)

Comment: @entne Did you run my revised code?  It does exactly that.

Comment: I did'nt notice your revision. It works indeed, thank you very much! What modification made the difference? The `\maketitle` being not at the beginning of the line? I got another issue (already before this problem) with reformatting a subsubsection header, but I will post it in a new topic soon. Again, thanks.